# Getting 'connection time out' error each time on the same step in sqlmap

Tags: sqlmap

On running sqlmap, I always get an error on following step and then connection gets timed out.

[11:44:14] [INFO] testing 'AND boolean-based blind - WHERE or HAVING clause'

[11:46:15] [CRITICAL] connection timed out to the target url or proxy, sqlmap is going to retry the request

I also increased the timeout, but no use.
Can I skip this particular Test Case(testing 'AND boolean-based blind - WHERE or HAVING clause' ) of sqlmap or Is der any other solution for this?

Comment: can you show the code??

Answer (score 2):

you can increase the for example

python sqlmap.py -u 'http://wyousite.com/any.php?page_id=2' --timeout 100

OR

some time it happens due to agent related issue so also try this --random-agent

python sqlmap.py -u 'http://www.chellosit.com/node.php?page_id=2' --random-agent

Comment: "--timeout 100" Work it!

Answer (score 0):

i have this issue all the time, but it got fixed once by adding --tamper="between.py". Also try other tamper scripts as your queries might be filtered by firewall

Comment: Does the tool itself have this between.py file or do we have to download it?